# Highcharts Heatmap colorAxis min 0 Max 1

Tags: highcharts

I have some values between 0 and 1 that I want to show in a heatmap graphic in highcharts.
The gradient bar should be between 0 and 1, but it is bigger and when I select a cell in the graphic, the color does not match with the color in the gradient bar.

```
    colorAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 1,
        minColor: '#FFFFFF',
        maxColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
        tickPositions: [0, 0.5, 1]
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n13vuaja/

For values between 0 and 150 it works: http://jsfiddle.net/2p2bunnm/

but with values between 0 and 1, even adding the min: 0, max:1, does not match the cursor in the gradient bar with the color.

any idea how to make the gradient bar cursor select the proper color between 0 and 1?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/3379) with heatmaps. Currently the workaround seems to be removing the line

```
this.isXAxis = true;
```

in the colorAxis `init` function of the heatmap module (line 93 in `heatmap.src.js`).

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a bug in highcharts. Their demo if scaled down to small value doesn't match the colorAxis correctly to the legend color (http://jsfiddle.net/3188gubh/).

E.g. 0 is not completely white on the legend, but is on the chart.

```
Without a code block stackoverflow doesn't let me post a link to jsfiddle :(
```